# Cast a text object to a value

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

In my report, I have a text object named `cardsCreditPayOff` which I populate by running this code:

```
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject textcardsCreditPayOff =
    (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject)
DReport.Section4.ReportObjects["cardsCreditPayOff"];
textcardsCreditPayOff.Text = "25
```

I want to add the value of that text object to one of my formulas. Something like:

```
{#RTotal10} + {#RTotal11} + "cardsCreditPayOff"
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a `TextObject` try using `FormulaFieldDefinition`.

This should allow you to put *cardsCreditPayOff* into a formula which can be more easily cast as a value than a text object:

```
{#RTotal10} + {#RTotal11} + {@cardsCreditPayOff}
```